# Instagram Real-time API in C#

Tags: c#, api, real-time, instagram

Is there any C# wrapper that supports Instagram Real-time API? I'd like to subscribe and receive updates in my application.

I've checked InstaSharp, but it doesn't seem to have the real-time functionality.

Comment: From [the documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/), "When we have new updates to send your server, we do a simple POST with a payload containing updates to a URL on your server. This callback URL must support GET and POST methods."  So it looks like you don't need an Instagram library - just a web server to process communication from Instagram?

Answer (score 1):

I have looked into this once before and I didn't see anything that worked quite like how you are thinking. I think you have to almost create everything from the ground up. How I am not exactly sure though. I'll try to do some research on this and post back if I find anything.

Best of Luck!

Comment: https://github.com/vespassassina/.NET-Instagram-API-Wrapper

Check this out. It may help some, not sure. Can't confirm anything about it since I don't have a foundation to test it with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on an application that interacts with Instagram API, and was looking for some kind of wrapper too, but I didn't found one that fits my needs. So, I began to develop my own Instagram wrapper. Is not a full wrapper, but is working, and can show you how go ahead... 
  I'm using it to subscribe me to real-time updates, and request for data (mostly media) converting json into .Net objects.
  Download it from here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3y0e0srx5rm1g88/AAB48GJKNTUAK_BniH5Cvf7ua?dl=0

Comment: hi, can you share it again? or send it to my email?